# Function not returning anything when using switch case

Tags: php, exception, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

If I return an `array` before `SWITCH` condition it works fine but if try to return something after `SWITCH` condition (even hardcoded array) it does not return anything. Also it does not go in any `CASE`, not even `DEFAULT`. Even print or echo does not work.

My `$e->getAwsErrorCode()` function is returning `InvalidSignatureException` but it is not entering into related switch case.

I checked error log and there is nothing there, no error or warning printed on the page.

```
private function rekognition_error_catch($e)
    {
        $arr_error = array();
        /*return [
            'error_code' => 34,
            'error_message' => 'Error'
        ];*/
        switch ($e->getAwsErrorCode()) {
            case 'InvalidParameterException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 71;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'InvalidS3ObjectException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 72;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'ImageTooLargeException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 73;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'AccessDeniedException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 74;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'InternalServerError':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 75;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'ThrottlingException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 76;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 77;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'InvalidImageFormatException':
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 78;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                break;
            case 'InvalidSignatureException': 
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 79;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
                echo '1';
                print_r($arr_error);
                break;
            default:
                //throw new Exception($e->getAwsErrorMessage(),80);
                $arr_error['error_code'] = 80;
                $arr_error['error_message'] = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
        }
        echo '2';
        print_r($arr_error);
        return [
          'error_code' => 34,
          'error_message' => 'Error'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `case 'InvalidSignatureException': 79;` wut m8?

Comment: @bassxzero Its a typo, I have corrected it

Comment: Why do you repeat `$arr_error['error_message'] = ...` so much?

Answer (score -1):

Your cases set `$arr_array`, but never return it anywhere, you always return a default value of `[ 'error_code' => 34, 'error_message' => 'Error' ]`, therefore, you need to check if values in that array are set, so;

```
if (!empty($arr_error['error_code']))
{
    return $arr_error;
}
return [
  'error_code' => 34,
  'error_message' => 'Error'
];
```

The above checks to see if the error code is set in the `$arr_error` and if it is, will use this, otherwise, your default `34` error is returned

Just as a point of note, you call `$e->getAwsErrorMessage()` an awful lot, storing this will make it a little simpler, so for example;

```
$arr_error = array();
$err_message = $e->getAwsErrorCode();
switch ($err_message) {
    case 'InvalidParameterException':
        $arr_error['error_code'] = 71;
        $arr_error['error_message'] = $err_message;
        break;
    /* Your other code, just using $err_message instead of $e->getAwsErrorCode()
    This will save some overhead from the function calls */
}
```

Comment: I wanted to say that it does not even return static array which I have placed at the bottome

Answer (score -2):

If your switch case does not return any value at that time you have to put default case in your switch case.. default is the case which is execute when any other case will not match..